# ion-toggle submits the form

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have the following simple code:

```
@Page({
    template: `
      <ion-content>
        <form (submit)="submit()">
          <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Some Toggle</ion-label>
              <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggle"></ion-toggle>
          </ion-item>

          <div *ngIf="toggle">some content 1</div>
          <div *ngIf="!toggle">some content 2</div>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </ion-content>
    `,
})
export class TestPage{

  submit(){
    console.log("form submit");
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I click on the toggle the form calls the submit function.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't use Ionic. But when you say toggle-button, does it mean `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`?

Comment: No, when I say toggle-button I mean `<ion-toggle>` which is an ionic-component that holds a boolean like a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the submit function call in the submit button solved my problem:

```
@Page({
    template: `
      <ion-content>
        <form>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Some Toggle</ion-label>
              <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggle"></ion-toggle>
          </ion-item>

          <div *ngIf="toggle">some content 1</div>
          <div *ngIf="!toggle">some content 2</div>

            <button type="submit" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </ion-content>
    `,
})
export class TestPage{

  submit(){
    console.log("form submit");
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have two-way-binding on the `toggle` property and you bind your `ngIf`s on this property. This means that its updates are automatically taken into account without having to submit the form.

To take into account updates only when submitting, you need to use another property. Something like that:

```
@Page({
  template: `
    <ion-content>
      <form (submit)="submit()">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Some Toggle</ion-label>
            <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="toggle"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>

        <div *ngIf="panelToggle">some content 1</div> <-------
        <div *ngIf="!panelToggle">some content 2</div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </ion-content>
    `,
})
export class TestPage{
  submit() {
    console.log("form submit");
    this.panelToggle = this.toggle; // <--------
  }
}
```

Comment: No you did not understand my question. When I click on the toggle the form is submitted. How can I prevent the toggle to do this? I only want to submit the form when clicking on the submit button